# SQL query to get data from 2 db and match field by date

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 db, from one with the following query I get below data.

```
select COMParee.IDAREA as Lettore
    , TIMBACCESSI.CODICEBADGE as [Numero tessera]
    , COGNOME as Cognome
    , NOME as Nome
    , AZIENDE.DESCR as Azienda
    , FORMAT(DATAORA,'HH:mm') as Ora
    , FORMAT(dataora,'dd/MM/yyyy') as Data
    , iif(verso = 0,'U','E') as Flusso 
from timbaccessi
join badge on badge.codice = timbaccessi.codicebadge
join anagrafico on anagrafico.ID = badge.IDUTILIZZATORE
join profilo on profilo.IDUTILIZZATORE = badge.IDUTILIZZATORE
join aziende on aziende.id = profilo.IDAZIENDA
join terminali on terminali.id = TIMBACCESSI.IDTERMINALE
join comparee on terminali.id = COMPAREE.IDTERMINALE
where DATAORA >= @DataDa
    and DATAORA <= @DataA

idArea  Badge       Name    Name    Note    Time    Date
1000000 0000001730  BLABLA  ROBERTO XXXX    06:42   09/10/2019  
1000000 0000001719  BLABLA  CLAUDIO XXXX    11:53   13/10/2019
```

The first field "1000000" is an id.
In a different db I have 1 to multiple records associated to that id in a specific data range. Basically it's the cronology of the name of that unit in different periods. Like:

```
idArea  Descr From       To
1000000 Test1 01/10/2019 10/10/2019
1000000 Test2 11/10/2019 15/10/2019
```

What I want is modify the first query to obtain this:

```
Test1 0000001730    BLABLA  ROBERTO XXXX    06:42   09/10/2019  
Test2 0000001719    BLABLA  CLAUDIO XXXX    11:53   13/10/2019
```

So instead of the id I want to get the name associated to that id in that period.

Comment: Why can't you just use a join? And no idea where the last column of data came from??

Comment: @SeanLange sorry the last column was a typo, I edited the post. I can't just use a join, I want to get the name in second db by matching the period of validity and the date of the first query results. Anyway, what kind of join would you make?

Comment: I don't know because I can't see your tables or really understand the situation here. My guess is this could be a correlated subquery or a cross apply.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you! Cross apply is what I needed, I wasn't aware of its existence! If you want to make it like an answer (maybe linking to a cross apply explanation) I mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sean Lange suggested, I solved my problem using a Cross Apply.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/